# Is it possible to let a programm ignore rp_filtering?

Tags: linux, networking

I am trying to discover all devices (in my case cameras) in my local network.
These cameras can have static/dhcp/LLA IP configuration and therefore may not be reachable.

I am sending a limited broadcast (255.255.255.255) and get a response from a misconfigured camera. Here the rp_filter comes into action and discards it.
Turned off, everything works as expected.

Is there a possibility to allow a program to get the responses without turning the filter off?